# Ambiguous transitive verb whose meaning is determined by its subject

Tags: linguistics, transitive-verbs

I am looking for an example of a transitive verb with an ambiguous meaning that is determined by its subject.

To explain what I mean, here is an example of a transitive verb whose meaning is modified by the object to which it is applied: to bend. You can bend a bow or you can bend the truth. Arguably, these give two different meanings of the same verb.

Now, can you think of a similar effect induced by the subject that performs the action of a verb? I am looking for a similar case where the change of meaning comes from the subject.

I hope this is clear. Thanks!

(For those interested in why I need this, I am researching a specific model in computational linguistics and want to test it on such a verb, if it exists.)

Comment: The defensive line rushed the quarterback. Later, at dinner, when his wife called for the check he said, "Don't rush me!"

Comment: Are you looking for a [verb] that changes its meaning depending on how the subject [verb]s, or are you looking for a [verb] that changes according to what the subject is?

Comment: @user2370114 I am looking for the latter.

Comment: @Brian Donovan Thanks! Interestingly, what seems to happen in your example is that further context is necessary to understand the meaning of the second use of rush (she rushes him).

Comment: The cleaver cleaves. The lover cleaves.

Comment: *Every* word (with rare exceptions) defines its contextual meaning from various elements of the sentence, and also from the broader context. Verbs are one example of the general phenomenon. Practically, no English word stands by its itself semantically.

Comment: Also, The bow bends. The truth bends. Now the object is a subject, right?

Comment: @Kris I agree with you. Of course, the meaning of each word is to be interpreted in context (this context is potentially very large: the surrounding words, the whole sentence, the whole document, the tone etc.). Now, imagine that we define meaning as all the possible contexts (whatever context you are interested in) in which a word is likely to appear. In this framework, the verb "to bend" can appear in a variety of different contexts. However, if you consider the phrase "to bend the truth" you see that the contexts in which the verb bend can appear has been severely restricted.

Comment: Of course this is true for virtually every word in the English language. But, in some cases this behaviour is more clear cut, like in verbs that are used metaphorically in certain contexts (like the example above). This is why we have multiple definitions of the same verbs in the dictionary: to classify these usages. But ultimately, you are right. Meaning is use and there are as many uses as there are contexts!

Comment: Sorry, the example does not work for me *at all*. I fail to see a substantial difference in meaning between "bend a bow" and "bend the truth" — which is little wonder seeing how the latter is *directly derived* from the former. (That's the whole point of a metaphor. You take a word and apply it to something it is normally not applied to. But it is still the exact same word with the exact same meaning.) Edit: oh, and I'm only just noticing John Lawler has already said the same thing.

Comment: @SrJoven, yes, now the relevant contextual differentia are subjects, but now the verbs are intransitive, where OP specified transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer runs a program.
The river runs a waterwheel.
The racer runs a race.

For many transitive definitions of [run](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run) there are variations based upon subject and object.

Comment: transitive verbs?

Comment: @user312440 right. Needed an object. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You probly need to read about how ***[Metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf)*** work.
As you point out, bending the law is not the same as bending a bow.
But that's because bending the law is not really *bending*.

*Bending* has a physical sense of torsion caused by stress, archetypically provided by human agency.
Anything that can be *bent* is not rigid -- rigid things **break** under stress.
There is already a metaphor ***breaking*** the law, meaning to disobey it.

***Bending*** the law is an extension of that theme, since things that are bent are not broken.
But they **do** change their shape, and may allow other things to pass without breaking.
And that's why *bend the law* means what it does -- not because it says so in the dictionary,
but because that's the way people extend the meaning metaphorically.

Virtually all extra non-physical senses of any word (particularly verbs) come from [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf),
whether they're obvious like this one or covert. Once you see how it works, they're easy to identify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that, in most cases, the behaviour I am describing comes from a metaphorical use of a transitive verb. Our mind works by analogy. My question is: can such metaphorical use of a verb arise from the subject and not the object?

Comment: Wrong question. It doesn't arise from either subject or object. It arises from the verb. Verbs determine what kinds of subjects and objects they can have, and whether they can have objects at all. Nouns are just placeholders for identification; predicates (verb phrases, verbs, predicate adjectives, predicate nouns) are where the meaning is. Subjects and objects may identify a particular metaphor theme in use, but so can adverbs, articles, or anything else that evokes a different metaphoric frame.

Comment: I agree that we can infer the meaning of the verb from its common physical sense - we are shown examples of what bending an object is and are able to associate this experience to our mental representation of the word. By analogy, we extend its meaning to other - more abstract - objects (like the law or truth). But, at the root of all this remains our shared experience of what bending is physically, unifying all possible uses of the verb. However, by saying this, we admit that there are at least two distinct ways in which we can describe the use of the predicate: it can be metaphorical or not

Comment: (i.e faithful to some original meaning, more immediately grounded in our common experience as humans). Thus, if I write "you bend a stick", I know that I am using the verb in the latter sense. If I write "you bend the law", I use it metaphorically. Now, we understand this immediately. But modelling what happens precisely is difficult and determining whether the use of a verb is metaphorical or not is a non trivial task for a computer. Typically, it is the object that gives us the essential clue in discriminating between possible uses of most verbs.

Comment: Therefore my question may be rephrased as follows: is there a verb for which the subject gives us more information than the object in determining this? I hope this clarifies what I meant.

Comment: @Robin: these comments finally provide some clarification for me, but even so — isn't the answer like pretty much any verb ever? I  am playing in my room, the radio is playing in my room. I fly to Africa, this bird flies to Africa. I dance, my thoughts dance. My nose smells, my armpit smells. I open, the door opens. I run, the PC runs. Really you could be doing this for hours. It might be harder to come up with a verb that *cannot* have two different meanings based on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

1. Westerners who don't know societal norms in China can easily suffer loss of face.
2. Those who play with fire can easily suffer loss of face.

right? The subject controls the meaning of the object and the verb. You could say that, stripped of its noun clause, #2 is weak because "those" is just a pronoun. And, who is to say that the antecedent it not "Westerners".